# Reverse image search using Google api

Tags: google-image-search

I am trying to write a java program which for loop the image files in a folder and
do reverse image search on google (just trying to do with one image in this question)

I find some example like below and the result will give me a url that preformed the reverse image search.
While I am wondering how can I download one of the image from the result site.

Some things to add is that I have read the new google api(?) and I find that it only allow me to do search 100/day, hence I choose to use the old version(?) although it warn me the method are deprecated.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class ReverseImageSearch{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    try {
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      String url="https://www.google.co.in/searchbyimage/upload";
      String imageFile="C:\\Users\\Chan\\Desktop\\pixiv29706591.jpg";
      HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

      MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
      entity.addPart("encoded_image", new FileBody(new File(imageFile)));
      entity.addPart("image_url",new StringBody(""));
      entity.addPart("image_content",new StringBody(""));
      entity.addPart("filename",new StringBody(""));
      entity.addPart("h1",new StringBody("en"));
      entity.addPart("bih",new StringBody("179"));
      entity.addPart("biw",new StringBody("1600"));

      post.setEntity(entity);
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));         

      String line = "";
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.indexOf("HREF")>0)
            System.out.println(line.substring(8));
           //Problem:
           // get one of the result image from the sites
           // and store it in my PC


      }

    }catch (ClientProtocolException cpx){
      cpx.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException ioex){
      ioex.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```